# Safe & fastest way to store and retrieve data from mysql databae using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, database-performance

I have seen a lot of function to store data in database using php which are following :

(1) Serialization used by many websites like wordpress etc. and it seems good but most of forum said it not a good way to store data so why these forum use serialization to store data?

(2) Json is another way to store data.

(3) mysql_real_escape_string is another way to store data.

(4) addslashes use with stripslashes. but addslashes insert data with slashes which is not good in my opinion because it violet database.

(5) we can also use php function to sanitize data like get_magic_quotes_gpc().

Please explain what is advantage and disadvantage of their and when should they use.

Comment: I think you should have taken the BLUE pill.

Comment: What does "the fastest" mean in your world? Serialization and JSON-encoding has nothing to do with speed. Whether you serialze something or save bunch of random text, that's all the same to MySQL. Same goes with JSON-serialization. It receives data on a socket and writes it to the disk. Therefore, take one step back and describe what you're really after instead of listing unrelated terms.

Comment: @N.B. here fastest means performance of storing and retrieving data from database.

Comment: That "speed" depends on the hardware where database daemon runs and underlying storage plus database configuration. Whether you store serialized object or json-encoded objects or regular textual data - that's all the same to MySQL. It won't write down 4 kb of serialized data any faster than it will write down 4kb of ASCII text.

Comment: @N.B. I would say that while mysql does not see the difference between the 2 the additional overhead of encoding/decoding, extra characters for the encoding and the fact that performing a query on columns of data is now almost impossible are a significant punishment.

Comment: @DamianNikodem - what you brought up is another pair of sleeves. Of course, additional computation for serializing / decoding plays a role. However, it's still irrelevant for MySQL. It's also not the factor that determines significant speed gain or loss. It's also silly to store serialized data into *relational* database since one can't query that data, which makes MySQL a glorified text file. Basically, the whole problem presented by OP can be solved by choosing the right tool for the job and MySQL doesn't appear to be that tool.

Comment: @N.B. I completely agree with you, OP mentioned that Wordpress manages storage like this so I googled it, Turns out that WP does this to store plugin settings ( which makes sense since it is a lazy way to allow plugins to store data)

it appears that the OP is more likely than not struggling a lot with a lot of database concepts due to the fact that his question seems to confuse methods of data serialization and data escape...

Answer (score 1):

php PDO and Stored Procedures are the canonical 'best' way to do mysql data access.

Comment: Okay I got your answer then why we use JSON , Serialization and others. Wordpress websites use serialize data to store. why ?

Comment: @neo Using those as data wrappers (json, serialization, etc. ) as a encoding mechanism is simply a lazy way to cram more data into a single column, The cost of using such methods is a speed decrease, increased memory usage, and potential security issues.. PDO with prepared statements and writing the raw data only can be used to significantly increase both security and speed of database access.(It also has the benefit of being immune to SQL Injection attacks) Products such as WP typically use serialized data to store "plugin configuration" so a plugin author is given a 'simpler' persistence API

Comment: Okay, and what about get_magic_quotes_gpc() ,mysql_real_escape_strings()  ?